# Avoid duplicate Dockerfile

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, raspberry-pi

I'm working on a .NET Core application that is shipped via Docker. My development environment is a Windows machine using Linux containers. The production environment is a Raspberry Pi.

Since the architectures between development and production differ (`x64` vs. `ARM`), I have two different Dockerfile that only differ in exactly one line (the base image):

- Development on `x64`: `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base`
- Production on `ARM`: `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim-arm32v7 AS base`

Is it possible to avoid the two different files? If yes, how can I do so? Is it possible to have something like an `if` or can I reference another file (e. g. `Dockerfile.common`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For simple string substitutions like this you can use a Dockerfile [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg).  If you're using this to set a `FROM` base image, [it needs to be specified before any `FROM` lines](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact).  (For other uses it needs to be specified after the `FROM` line in each image stage that needs it.)

```sh
ARG BASE_IMAGE=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} AS base
```

If you're building on ARM then you need to supply a [`docker build --build-arg` option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg)

```sh
docker build \
  --build-arg BASE_IMAGE=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim-arm32v7 \
  .
```

Docker doesn't have any conditionals or file inclusion capabilities beyond this.